# Convex cones in $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: convex-analysis

Are the following sets convex cones:

### 1.$\{x\in\Bbb R^n:\langle a,x\rangle\leq 0, a\neq 0 \}$ 
 2.$\{x\in\Bbb R^n:\langle a,x\rangle\lt 0, a\neq 0 \}$ ?

We say $C\subset \Bbb R^n$ is a cone if $\forall x \in C$ and $\lambda>0$, $\lambda x \in C$. A convex cone is a cone that is a convex set. 
 I drew the sets in $\Bbb R^2$ and from that we can see that both sets are convex cones. Is there a more formal proof?

Comment: Yes, there are more formal proofs. Namely, the ones where you check if the sets satisfy the conditions you are asking.

Comment: I know how to check if it is convex, but how should I go about checking if it is a cone?

Comment: It appears you've written it, have you not?

Comment: Yes. Let $z, y \in $ $\{x\in\Bbb R^n| \langle a, x \rangle \leq0, a\neq 0$}. Then $\langle a, z \rangle \leq0$ and $\langle a, y \rangle \leq0$. Let $\lambda \in [0,1]$. Then
$\langle a, \lambda z+ (1-\lambda) y\rangle = \langle a, \lambda z\rangle  + \langle a, (1-\lambda) y\rangle = \lambda\langle a,  z\rangle + (1-\lambda)\langle a, y \rangle \leq \lambda*0 + (1-\lambda)*0= 0$. Hence  $\lambda z+ (1-\lambda) y \in \{x\in\Bbb R^n| \langle a, x \rangle \leq0, a\neq 0$}.

Comment: Let $z \in $ $\{x\in\Bbb R^n| \langle a, x \rangle \leq0, a\neq 0$}. Then $\langle a, z \rangle \leq0$. Let $\lambda \in [0,1]$. Then
$\langle a, \lambda z\rangle = \lambda \langle a, z\rangle \leq \lambda * 0=0 $. So the set is a cone.

Comment: Sorry to bother you all, I don't know why I just didn't follow the definitions, my bad.

Comment: you should add your solution as an answer instead of a comment, and then accept the answer :)

Comment: The vector $a$ should be outside the set. There is ambiguity the way it is stated. Should it be true for all $a\neq 0$? For some $a\neq 0$ etc.